# What is the default constructor for a Dart PolymerElement?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I just upgraded my dart polymer to `0.8.5` and I'm getting a new error in all of my custom elements.

`The class 'PolymerElement' does not have a default constructor`

This is preventing any of them from displaying. What is the appropriate fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that with the update, PolymerElement has a named constructor "created" that needs to be called.

I assume adding this to your code should fix it, given your component is named MyComponent:

```
MyComponent.created() : super.created();
```

Comment: Worked, thanks! What does the colon syntax mean in this example? And how can I write it so that I can run code on created?

Comment: The colon indicates a call to the super constructor. You can add a constructor body between {} after super.created().